# non-repetitive random number picker

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

I'm trying to create a non-repetitive random number picker, can anyone please point out what went wrong with it? thanks

```
var resultArray = [];

function pickRandom(){
  var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);

    resultArray.push(result);

  for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++){
     if(resultArray[i].includes(result))
     {
      pickRandom();
     } else {
      document.getElementById("result").value = result;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
var resultArray = [];
function pickRandom(){
  var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
  var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
    if(resultArray.includes(result))
    {
     pickRandom();
    } else {
     resultArray.push(result);
     document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
}
```

There were 2 issues with your code:
1. You pushed new element to the array first and then checked whether it is there in the array, so it returns true always. This causes infinite looping.
2. includes method is defined to check whether an element is there in an array or a character is there in a string. In your code, you have iterated through each element in array and then used includes method.

Comment: Check again, it does work. I made some changes in between. You might have checked old code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a check, if the length of the `resultArray` is equal to the count of the possible numbers and exit the loop.

```js
function pickRandom() {
    var min = +parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value),
        max = +parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value),
        result = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

    if (resultArray.length === max - min + 1) {
        document.getElementById("result").value = 'no more available';
        return;
    }
    if (resultArray.includes(result)) {
        pickRandom();
    } else {
        resultArray.push(result);
        document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
}

var resultArray = [];
```

```html
<input type="text" id="min" placeholder="min"> <input type="text" id="max" placeholder="max"> <button onclick="pickRandom()">Generate Random Number</button> <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="random number">
```